# How to convert an array in js to an array in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

This i code from js. I want to set up the same thing i C#, but don't know how. I have tried using arrays, but the information is supposed to be easy to update without changing the rest of the code.

For example, i can get the summer price from:  `hotell[0].list[0].price_s.text`

Is there a way to do this in C#(visual studio), where you can put information like this in an array?

```
var hotell = [];

hotell[0] = {
    city: "New York",
    liste: [
        {name: "Aurora", price_s: 590, price_v: 690},
        {name: "Downtown", price_s: 660, price_v: 750},
        {name: "City Hall", price_s: 450, price_v: 530},
        ]
};
```

Comment: You'll have to define classes for `Hotel` and the `liste` type, and then initialize them

Comment: try google for arrays of classes - I found this link for you there are many more : http://www.functionx.com/csharp/arrays/Lesson03.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Model class named as Hotel which is having two properties named as "city" and "liste". "liste" is nothing but a `List<HotelDetails>` class

```
public class HotelDetails
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int price_s { get; set; }
    public int price_v { get; set; }
}

public class Hotel
{
    public string city { get; set; }
    public List<HotelDetails> liste { get; set; }
}
```

Next you need to convert your array to an json object and make an ajax call to your webmethod(if asp.net web form application) or make a call to your controller action (if asp.net MVC application) and pass your json object as a parameter.

After that you can play with your Hotel class

Answer (score 0):

Classes for both `Hotel` and items within `Liste` would be the better implementation, like @degant mentioned.

However, you could have a list of `tuple<string, int, int>`.

```
var hotel1 = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>
{
        new Tuple<string, int, int>("Aurora", 590, 690),
        new Tuple<string, int, int>("Downtown", 660, 750),
        new Tuple<string, int, int>("City Hall", 450, 530)
};
```

You could then store all the Hotels in a dictionary:

```
    var allhotels = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int, int>>>
    {
        {"Hotel1", storage}
    };
```

Or:

```
    var allhotels = new Dictionary<string, List<Tuple<string, int, int>>>(); 
    allhotels.Add("Hotel1", storage);
```

But as you can see it get complicated rather quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest would probably be to create a class which represents your data.

```
class Hotel { string name; int price_s; price_v;}
```

Then you could either create a dictionary where the key is the citys name and the value is a list of hotels:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Hotel>> hotels;
```

Or you could create another class for this:

```
class HotelsPerCity{ string city; List<Hotel> hotels; }
```

And just keep the HotelsPerCity in a list:

```
List<HotelsPerCity> hotels;
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you could use anonymous classes for this, doing something like below

```
var hotell = new []{
    new {city = "New York",
    liste= new[]{
        new{name= "Aurora", price_s = 590, price_v = 690},
        new {name= "Downtown", price_s = 660, price_v = 750},
        new {name= "City Hall", price_s= 450, price_v= 530},
        }
}};

Console.WriteLine(hotell[0].liste[1]);
```

The problem here is that the `var` keyword is inferred to a specific class by the compiler. That is, anonymous classes are contructed for a type containing fields `string name`, `int price_s` and `int price_v`, as well an anonymous class for the actual Hotels.

Anonymous classes are meant to be shortlived and the only way you would be able to return you `hotell` object from a method would be as an object causing you to have to cast it to your anonymous type later on. As it is anonymous this is hard :). You could probably also go with dynamics, but these are slow and afaik reflection base.

IE: You are in a strongly typed language and is better of declaring your classes.

Having Hotel and Suite classes

```
class Room {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int price_s {get;set;}
    public int price_v {get;set;}
}

class Hotel {
   public string city {get;set;}
   public List<Room> liste {get;set;}
}
```

you could get reasonably simple initialization not unlike (but also not identical to js):

```
var hotel = new Hotel[]{
    new Hotel{city = "New York",
    liste= new List<Room>{
        new Room{name= "Aurora", price_s = 590, price_v = 690},
        new Room{name= "Downtown", price_s = 660, price_v = 750},
        new Room{name= "City Hall", price_s= 450, price_v= 530},
        }
}};
```

which could be passed around with the corresponding types. Please note that the properties are usually capitalized i C#.